# VBA Excel: How to remove duplicates in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, range

I have the following below, but I'm having issues with the syntax. I want to set the current selection as a range, and I want to remove duplicates from that selection. How can I do this?

```
'remove duplicates
Columns("B:C").Select
Dim duplicates As Range
Set duplicates = Selection
ActiveSheet.duplicates.RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes)
```

Comment: just an aside, you can just write `Set duplicates = Columns("B:C")` and get rid of `Columns("B:C").Select`. You can also just write duplicates.removeduplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes` and get rid of `ActiveSheet`, since it's implied when you set the range variable.

Comment: You can also call `Columns("B:C").RemoveDuplicates` directly without setting the reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis when calling RemoveDuplicates if the function is not returning any value, like this:

```
selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Or you can use the call statement in the front. That way, your syntax is correct.